# How should i do the references in my Mongodb DB

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing a simple forum mongodb DB, with categories,topics,posts and users.

My question is :

How should i do the references between `categories`,`topics` and `posts` to be as faster and lighter as posible, with the `_id` or `nesting objects` like this?

```
categories{category:'categoryname',
           topics:{topic:'topic',
                   posts:{post:'post',
                          user:'_idfromusers'
                         }
                   }               
          }
```

Suppose category has **a very very big number of topics**, and topics has **a very very big number of posts**.

Comment: See more about data model for Mongodb on page http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/  I use it to choose an approach for storing data in database

Comment: Also, please give a certain focus in your question on how will MongoDB behave based on it's limits (collections and documents). Nesting the data seems feasible from a theoretical point of view (as explained in @jmen7070 's link), but you could hit a wall as soon as you pass certain size limits.

Comment: Then, if i do a Embedded model with a big number of nested objects with nested objects inside, it can crash if it exceed the mongodb colection's or document's size limit?

Comment: @shkliciouz Yes, indeed. You must figure out how big your data will be and if Mongo will be able to handle it.